# Tesseract 3.02 - How to properly free up memory?

Tags: c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I found memory leaking from my very simple app running with tesseract api. I know tesseract api saying that I have to delete [] the char array from GetUTF8Text() but it crashed for my case. Here is the block of code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
Mat plate_segments = imread(argv[1], 0);
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *myOCR = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
myOCR->SetPageSegMode(tesseract::PSM_AUTO);
if (myOCR->Init("./", "newnz+oldnz")) {

        std::cerr << "Could not initialize tesseract." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }
myOCR->SetVariable("tessedit_char_blacklist","abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`~!@#$%^&*()_+-={}[]|\':;/?.<,>");
myOCR->SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist","ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789");
myOCR->SetImage((uchar*) plate_segments.data,plate_segments.size().width, plate_segments.size().height, plate_segments.channels(), plate_segments.step1());
myOCR->Recognize(0);
char* license_result = myOCR->GetUTF8Text();
printf("OCR output:\n%s", license_result );
    delete [] license_result; // CAUSE CRASH
myOCR->Clear();
myOCR->End();
return 0;}
```

Do I need to do "delete myOCR"? I did try but it crashes as well.

Comment: This is wrong `myOCR->~TessBaseAPI();`, should be `delete myOCR;`. Since you are getting crashes on deletes it indicates that your program is causing *heap corruption*. Unfortunately I don't have enough of the program to be able to guess where that is happening. But I would say something has gone wrong *before* you call this code. Perhaps something is wrong when you initialize `plate_segments`?

Comment: I did tried removing myOCR->~TessBaseAPI() and use delete myOCR and my program crashed too, thats why I got so confused. myOCR->~TessBaseAPI() was only used when i ran out of idea.

Comment: As for plate_segments, it seems to work properly, tesseract can recognize it, I followed a few tutorial about using opencv Mat format for tesseract and the parameters are all similiar.

Comment: Unfortunately 'working properly' is not the same as without bugs. Your mistake is thinking that just because it crashes when you delete there must be something wrong with the delete, but it's not true. Your program has classic symptoms of heap corruption, that corruption has happened earlier in the program. I can't tell where because I can't see the rest of the code. Just because plate_segments seems to work correctly does not mean that it's not corrupting the heap. But only a guess on my part, if you want more help post more code.

Comment: Full code updated, please review

Comment: OK, that's quite a bit simpler than I expected. I'm not sure I can help much as I'm not familar with either library you are using. Obviously you are not using OpenCV incorrectly, I'll have to take your word that you're using tesseract correctly. But clearly something is going wrong.

Comment: That is exactly what I am confused about, no one else seems to have this problem.

Comment: Hi John, thank you so much for the effort of helping, I manage to have it work without errors. Here is what happened, tesseract library I have been using in VS2010 was built in VS2008. I rebuilt the library in VS2010 then it works all fine now.

Answer (score -1):

try

```
delete myOCR;
myOCR=nullptr;
```

So, you don't need to call

```
myOCR->Clear();
myOCR->End();
```

becouse delete did it for you! (it's call  ~TessBaseAPI() )